# Unify list items pairwise

Tags: python, list-comprehension

Given a list

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

with `2n` elements

How do I get the list

```
[1+2,3+4,5+6]
```

with `n` elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [`itertools` recipes section](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes):

```
def grouper(n, iterable, fillvalue=None):
    "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
    # grouper(3, 'ABCDEFG', 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return izip_longest(fillvalue=fillvalue, *args)
```

then call with:

```
for paired in grouper(2, inputlist):
    # paired is a tuple of two elements from the inputlist at a time.
```

`grouper` returns an iterator; if you *have* to have a list, simply consume the iterable into a new list:

```
newlist = list(grouper(2, inputlist))
```

Comment: what if `izip_longest` is not defined (python2, I really can't use py3)?

Comment: It is defined in Python 2; python 2.6 and up, see http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest

Answer (score 2):

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
b = [a[i]+a[i+1] for i in xrange(0,len(a),2)]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
li = [1,2,10,20,100,200,2000,3000,2,2,3,3,5,5]
print li

it = iter(li)
if len(li)%2==0:
    print [x+it.next() for x in it]
```

gives

```
[1, 2, 10, 20, 100, 200, 2000, 3000, 2, 2, 3, 3, 5, 5]
[3, 30, 300, 5000, 4, 6, 10]
```